# How to derive a conclusion with the scatterplot that we made using the data in a quantitative research?

Tags: operations-research

How can we write the result section by using the scatter plot that we made using the data in a quantitative research. Also most importantly if the scatter plot shows no correlation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“The plot shows no observable correlation; even if the correlation is statistically significantly different from zero, we do not see practical significance.”

This way, you acknowledge that you performed your analysis by graphical examination of the data, and you say that you do not see an interesting pattern, even if there is a slight pattern in the data.